# Issue in whereJsonContains() laravel 5.8 when sending params as raw JSON in Rest API

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.8, and sending params as raw JSON in Rest API, but `whereJsonContains()` is not working, It does not give me any response. But when I send it as form data it works.

This is working on my local machine with same configuration

```
$data=DB::table('product_common_details')->whereJsonContains('service_id',$r->service_id)->where('status',1)->where('publish',1)->get();
```

Comment: What is the datatype for the column "service_id" and  value "$r->service_id"?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the datatypes difference between column and the value.

```
// [1, 2, 3] Incase of integers or decimal or double etc
->whereJsonContains('service_id', $r->service_id)   // Works.
->whereJsonContains('service_id', '$r->service_id') // Doesn't work.

// ["1", "2", "3"] Incase of string or varchar
->whereJsonContains('service_id', '$r->service_id') // Works.
->whereJsonContains('service_id', $r->service_id)   // Doesn't work.
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Actually the query works when i call api through multipart/form-data 

but when i call the api through Application/json and send params in json then this qyery doesnot work